# How to add Tabbarcontroller to existing view in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am unable to add tabbarcontroller in my existing view in my app. I dont want a tab bar application but tabbar in oneof my view in application.Can someone please Help me

Answer (score 1):

To show a view that has got a tab bar in it, you don't need to have a tab bar base application.

Simply create a `UITabBarController` and then add its `view` to your main view (as a subview or how ever it is ok for you). You can create the `UITabBarController` either in IB or programmatically.